# Table of contents is the running title

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

I have the following problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents*

\chapter*{Introduction}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Introduction}}
```

And the problem is that I want the running title (in the headers of pages of this chapter) to be only "Introduction"  while it is "Table of Contents". I've tried to use

```
\chaptermark{Introduction}
```

but then the running title is "Chapter 0. Introduction". I would like remove "Chapter 0" and to leave only "Introduction". The only thing I know that removes the word Chapter from running title in the page headers is

`\backmatter`

but it completely destroys the numbering of chapters which I don't want to change and creates unnecessary empty pages.  I would be very thankfull for any help.

Comment: the `book` class doesn't use the heading text of `\chapter*` to form running heads.  you can provide the desired running head content by inputting a line `\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}` immediately after the `\chapter*` line.

Comment: The book class doesn't have \tableofcontents*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Maybe package `unnumveredtotoc` can help (linked in tge LaTeX wikibok). But the might be something better. Can you provide a bit more context? Is that the only chapter without a numver or should all be unnumbered?